# Display templates - style block / media queries - remove //<![CDATA[

Tags: 2013, css, display-template

I'm having trouble inserting style block inside a display template.

See code below:

```
<a class="articleListing" href="_#= linkURL =#_" title="_#= $htmlEncode(carouselHeading) =#_">
      <style type="text/css">
        @media all and (max-width:767px){
            .carouselImage {
                background: url("_#= carouselImage =#_?RenditionID=5") no-repeat center center transparent;
            }       
        }      
       </style>

    <div class="carouselImage"> </div>
</a>
```

The style block get's like this

```
  <style>
  //<![CDATA[               
  @media all and (max-width:767px){                 
      .carouselImage{                       
          background: url("../466175.JPG?RenditionID=5") no-repeat center center transparent;                   
      }   
  }                    
  //]]>
  </style>
```

How can I insert a style block without

```
//<![CDATA[
```

Comment: This is a long shot, but it's not something to do with the $htmlencode in the anchor's attributes, right ? That he's eating up everything and encoding it ? Maybe it needs a ";" at the end.

Comment: - Maybe it needs a ";" at the end? Where exactly do you mean

Comment: Just a guess, but I meant this: title="_#= $htmlEncode(carouselHeading); =#_" -> after carouselheading)

Comment: Didn't make any difference. Probably I need to find some javascript that render out the style block

Comment: Check link for solution that may work

[sharepoint-2013-display-templates-media-queries-to-get-image-rendition][1]


  [1]: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91758/sharepoint-2013-display-templates-media-queries-to-get-image-rendition-on-im

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found here..

[check this link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91758/sharepoint-2013-display-templates-media-queries-to-get-image-rendition-on-im)

```
<!--#_
AddPostRenderCallback(ctx, function()
{    
     var width = $(window).width();
     var rendition = '?RenditionID=2'; 
     if(width <= 320){
         rendition = '?RenditionID=1';
     }
     jQuery('.image-to-fix').each(function(){
           jQuery(this).css('background-image', jQuery(this).attr('data-image') + rendition);
     });
});
_#-->
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. 
I faced same issue in custom Page layout and fixed it with this.

```
<!-- MS: <style type="text/css">-->
<!--
#pageContentTitle {display:none;}
-->
<!-- ME: </style>-->
```

Comment: Worked perfectly in my case to add custom CSS. Thanks!